# JSP page, how to redirect to my root directory?

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have created a button in JSP to redirect to my root directory.
<
input type="button" value="OK" onclick="document.location.href='.'"/>

Am I doing this right?

Answer (score 1):

This will redirect to the root directory

`document.location.href="/"`